# Dell C2722DE always charging my MBP

Tags: display, charging

I bought [this](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B08YXH5Q5W/) and everything's working perfectly.
Thing is, I don't seem the need to charge the MBP separately. The Dell monitor is charging it and it's always at 100% now.
Is there a way to bypass this and charge my MBP separately ?

Comment: Your MBP is designed to work plugged in to a charger all the time. It is also designed to use an external display only when it has mains power. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The Mojave MBP is always @ 100% because of the monitor's connectivity via USB-C - before I got the external Dell monitor, I always had the habit of charging the MBP at only 20% till 98% after which I disconnect.

Comment: Which model is the "Mojave MPB"? It’s the usb C connectivity  doing the charging.

Comment: I wanted to know if there's a solution for me to connect the MBP separately for charging and not have my monitor charge it all the time. If the issue is USB-C then does replacing the USB-C with a HDMI connector to the monitor solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to bypass this and stop it from charging. There's really no practical benefit to stopping charging at 98% every time. The positive effect for the life time of the battery is so very, very small.

If you still want to do it, then consider connecting your your MacBook Pro to the monitor via a cable that does not support charging. That could be for example using an USB-C to HDMI cable.

Please keep in mind though that your monitor has a built-in camera, speakers, ethernet, hotkey button, etc. These features will not work over a HDMI cable, but require USB connectivity. Instead of connecting the USB-C to USB-C cable to the monitor's USB-C port, you'll then need to have a cable that connect to the monitor's USB-B port.

There's no software available to the user in macOS that allows you to stop charging over USB-C from the monitor by way of GUI or command line. If you have an Intel MacBook Pro, you could try the third party software [Charge Limiter](https://github.com/godly-devotion/charge-limiter) for setting a maximum charge percentage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @jksoegaard - someone pointed out this to me - https://github.com/godly-devotion/charge-limiter - but since you've mentioned that "no practical benefit to stopping charging at 98% every time", I may skip installing that script from GitHub. But the laptop does gets heated up and cools down only when I power-off the monitor or switch on the room's air-conditioning.